# Is there any way to callback after document remove from collection by TTL?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My problem is "When users order an order, the email will be sent to user's email, with a link to confirm the order in the content. At this time, the amount of the products in the order will be reduced. After 24h, if user doesn't confirm by email link, the order will be delete and the amount of products will be back to database."

So I need a callback function to set the amount of products back? Is there another way to set expire?

Here is my Model order.js code:

```
const OrderSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    paid: {           
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    payment_method: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['local', 'paypal'],
        default: 'local'
    },
    status: {          
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    confirmed: {        // After order, users must confirm order by email link
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
        index: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

const Order = mongoose.model('Order', OrderSchema)

// After 24h, if user doesn't confirm by email link, the order will be delete
 OrderSchema.index({
    createdAt: 1
},{
    expireAfterSeconds: 24*60*60,
    partialFilterExpression : {
        confirmed: false
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try changeStreams https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found the solution by using 'cron' package

```
npm install cron
```

Here is my Controller order.js code:

```
const Order = require('../models/Order');
const Product = require('../models/Product');
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
...
const addOrder = async (req, res, next) => {
    ...
    await order.save();

        // After 24h, if user doesn't confirm by email link
        const thisTime = new Date();
        var job = new CronJob(' * * * * *', async() => {
            // Expire time, then stop a job
            var expire = new Date();
            if(expire - thisTime >= 24*60*60*1000){
                await job.stop();
            }
            },async () => {
                const orderNow = await Order.findById(order._id);
                // Check if confirm = false, then delete this order
                if(!orderNow.confirmed){
                    await Order.findByIdAndDelete(order._id);
                    // Update the amount of products in this order
                    for (let item of orderNow.order_list){
                        let productFound = await Product.findById(item.product);
                        if(productFound){
                            productFound.colors.find(i => i._id.toString() === item.color.toString()).amount = productFound.colors.find(i => i._id.toString() === item.color.toString()).amount + item.quantity;
                            await productFound.save();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            true, /* Start the job right now */
            'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh' /* Time zone of this job. */
        );

        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, code: 201, message: 'success', order });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
};
...
module.exports = {
    addOrder
}
```